# Why does this ASP.NET Gridview container doesn't keeps its width?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have the following scenario:

```
    .divContenedor
    {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .divGrilla
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updCondiciones">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="divContenedor">
                <div class="divGrilla">
                    <asp:GridView ID="dgCondiciones" runat="server"     Width="98%"    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        OnRowDataBound="dgCondiciones_RowDataBound" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="true"
                        BorderColor="#DCDCDC" AllowSorting="True" OnSortCommand="dgCondiciones_SortCommand"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="dgCondiciones_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="dgCondiciones_Sorting">
                        <Columns>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There are other divs inside "divContenedor" but they are not relevant.

The Gridview has a Width="98%" and it is inside a div with Width="100%". When I get rows which contain large text the GridView expands correctly up to 98% but when I get rows with shorter text it contracts. It should always keep the same width.

Since "divContenedor" and "divGrilla" have  Width="100%" they are supposed to expand up to the screen size, right?

I have debugged the page and I noticed that there is an additional div rendered between "divGrilla" and the Gridview (rendered as a table):

```
<div class="divGrilla">
  <div>
    <table id="dgCondiciones"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

"divGrilla" renders with Width="100%" and the Gridview (dgCondiciones) actually has a Width="98%". The problem is that dgCondiciones is adjusting to 98% of this additional div which seems to have a shorter width.

Can someone explain to me what is this additional div and if there is a way to keep the GridView width **WITHOUT** setting a specific width to each column and **WITHOUT** setting the Gridview width in "px"?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updCondiciones">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="divContenedor">
            <div class="divGrilla">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    OnRowDataBound="dgCondiciones_RowDataBound" PageSize="20" AllowPaging="true"
                    BorderColor="#DCDCDC" AllowSorting="True" OnSortCommand="dgCondiciones_SortCommand"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="dgCondiciones_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="dgCondiciones_Sorting">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="test" runat="server" Width="98%" >
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="98%" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="98%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You have written correct code,Only add< ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="98%" /> to your templatefield of column.
And Gridview is always render as table in html so our observation is correct.
only use itemstyle with with as per your requirement your issue will get resolved. 
Please let me if you will face any other issue while doing this.

Comment: I actually have 16 columns in the Gridview and as I said, I don't want to set each column width specifically. I would like them to automatically adjust according to the Gridview size, which should be 98% of the screen size.

Comment: you need to manage column width as per your content in such a way that adding of all columns with will be 100. For example you have 5 column give 20% width  to each column.